# The parameter of serializeDelData callback contains id field only

Tags: jqgrid

I use jgGrid 4.5.4. When a user presses the `Delete` button, I need to send two pieces of information to the server: the record ID, and record version (for optimistic locking). I know that `serializeDelData` callback can be used for this purpose:

```
serializeDelData:serializeDelDataCallback

...

function serializeDelDataCallback(data) {

    // The "data" argument has "id" and "oper" fields only! Where can I get other fields of the current grid row?
    ...
    return $.param(modifiedData);
}
```

However, the argument of the `serializeDelData` callback contains `id` and `oper` fields only. I use a similar callback for posting new and updated records - that callback provides all fields of the current row.

Where can I get other fields of the current grid row in the `serializeDelData` callback? (I need to get the row version which is a hidden field in the grid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use optimistic locking then the rows of the grid contains probably record version column. 
The most easy way to `onclickSubmit` callback (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2)) for example in the following form

```js
onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
    return {
        rowVer: $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "rowVersion")
    };
}
```

In the above code I suppose that you have column with the name `rowVersion` which hold record version which you need to send as `rowVer` param. In general you can use `getCell` in the same way inside of `serializeDelData`, but `onclickSubmit` seems me more simple. The returned properties of `onclickSubmit` will be combined with the standard parameters used by Delete, so you should have all information which you need.